# The right word for an assumption which is very likely true?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I think something, but I cannot prove it is true. Though it is very likely to be true. To use "assume" seems to be too weak, for me at least.

In a sentence: *"I assume global warming is not a phantasm."*

Is there another term? Or can I say *"strongly assume"*?

Or would *"I strongly suspect"* fit better?

Comment: As a native American English speaker, I don't think "assume" is weak.  It would be easier to give you choices if we knew exactly what you were trying to say; "assume" means, more or less, "believe, for the purposes of this discussion."  You could assume something, presume it, believe it, accept it, suppose it, affirm it, allege it, aver it, contend it, declare it, maintain it, take it for granted...the exact choice depends on exactly what you want to mean.

Comment: "...but I cannot *prove* it is true." Use *prove* (not *proof* which is a noun).

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

> I **strongly believe** that... or
>   It is my **strong belief** that...

If you have a strong set of facts but can't prove it, then you could use:

> I **understand** that... or
>   It is my **understanding** that...

These days I would not use *assume* in any serious context (in the US anyway), due to the now well known reply to its use - [***What Happens When You Assume***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svkgOsr7pUc)

Answer (score 1):

There are many words that describe believing an idea to be true, with different meanings and connotations.

"I assume X is true." You may or may not have good reason to believe X, but you will talk or act as if it is true. In mathematics, we often say, "Let us assume that X is the set of all real numbers such that ..." or whatever our definition of the problem is. In conversation people often say things like, "Okay, let's assume, for the sake of argument, that what you are saying is true. It is still not clear why that would mean ..." etc. People also use "assume" for ideas that they can't present evidence to prove, but are quite sure are true based on intuition, general experience, etc. Like, "Well, I assume that all human beings want to be happy." Or a conclusion based on admittedly thin evidence. "You say you will vote for Senator Jones? So I assume you are a Democrat."

I suppose at the other end would be "I know" or "I am certain that ..." These indicate absolute confidance that the statement is true. You could be wrong, of course, but you think the possibility that you are wrong is zero or so close to zero as not to be worth considering.

"I think that ..." You believe it is likely that it is true, but you are not certain.

"I suspect that ..." You think it is probably true, but your certainty is low. Probably more than 50% but far from 100%.

"I believe that ..." Ambiguous. In some contexts could mean that you are 100% certain, in others it could a probability. Often used in cases where there is not direct proof, or for matters of opinion. "Where is Bob?" "Umm, I believe he's in the conference room." Low level of certainty. "I believe that all men are created equal." I can't prove this, but I am very confidant that it is true.

"I conclude that ..." You have examined the evidence and this is where you think it leads. Generally used when your certainty is pretty high, but not necessarily.

In your example, you probably want to say "I think that ..." It depends on how certain you are and why.

I'm sure there are other words.

Comment: "I think that..." and "I'm sure...." is actually exactly what I want to express, but I need it a little bit more formal. Is "I strongly assume that..." actually dead wrong?

Comment: It's certainly not wrong. Many readers would take it to mean that you have no concrete evidence, which may or may not be what you intend to say. If you want to sound more formal, perhaps "I consider it very likely that"? Other posters, feel free to chime in with more alternatives.